# List of buildozer requirements to build an apk for Kivy-Python app

Tags: android, python-2.7, python-3.x, kivy

I would like to discuss an issue.

- What can be put to the `requirements=...` in the `buildozer.spec`?
  Is it necessary to put `sdl2` and `python2` so that the app works fine on the phone?
- Should it better be built using `android_new` or `android`?

I have the `main.py` code that depends on `kivy` modules and some of its widgets, and also `numpy`, and some built-in Python2 modules. The app works fine in Windows using Python2 (and also Python3), the app uses three `.py` files for storing functions and objects. When I deploy the app using `buildozer` to the phone, the app does not crash..but the `touch` for button does not work and the `Image` widget does not show. This is built using `buildozer android debug`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in my last comment on your other post, the default buildozer.spec produced by "buildozer init" should be enough to compile a working apk, including image and clickable button.
So it's not necessary to add sdl2 or python2 in your requirements.

"android_new" or "android"? Now it's called "android" and "android_old", so you might update your buildozer installation so it may resolves your others problems, but when I was using your version, I used "android_new".

Comment: Thanks. Yes I just tried to reinstall `buildozer`  for python2 by steps in this link https://github.com/kivy/buildozer . Now there is no `android_new`, but previous one has. How about adding `kivy==master` instead of `kivy`?

Comment: Adding "master" tell buildozer to grab the most recent "stable" version on github, it will grab a normally newer version than if you don't add it.  Theorically, you should use only "kivy", and if a weird bug appear, add the "master", but in practice, I always have the "master" in my specs haha.   Also, I also have "hostpython2" in my requirements, don't remember why exactly, but it was to fix a bug, It may help you

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it runs means your requirements are probably ok. As mentioned previously, I would update as "android_new" is now "android". That might fix the touch, but the missing image is probably a path issue. I would suggest posting on the kivy forums if you still have issues.

"kivy" should be enough for requirements, but also "python2" or "python3crystax" would be good to add to explicitly state which python version you want to use.